# Logstash: Migrating from one elastic search to another elastic search result in some additional properties

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, amazon-elasticsearch

I have been migrating one of the indexes from self-hosted Elasticsearch to Amazon ElasticSearch using Logstash. After successful migration what we found was some additional fields is getting added in the documents. How can we prevent it from getting added

Our Logstash config file

```
input {
 elasticsearch {
 hosts => ["https://staing-example.com:443"]
 user => "userName"
 password => "password"
 index => "testingindex"
 size => 100
 scroll => "1m"
 }
}

filter {

}

output {
 amazon_es {
 hosts => ["https://example.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com:443"]
 region => "us-east-1"
 aws_access_key_id => "access_key_id"
 aws_secret_access_key => "access_key_id"
 index => "testingindex"
}
stdout{
  codec => rubydebug
  }
}
```

The document in our selfhosted ElasticSearch

```
{
        "_index": "testingindex",
        "_type": "interaction-3",
        "_id": "38b23e7a-eafd-4163-a9f0-e2d9ffd5d2cf",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
           "customerId" : [
            "e177c1f8-1fbd-4b2e-82b8-760536e42742"
          ],
          "customProperty" : {
            "messageFrom" : [
              "BOT"
            ]
          },
          "userId" : [
            "e177c1f8-1fbd-4b2e-82b8-760536e42742"
          ],
          "uniqueIdentifier" : "2b027fc0-a517-49a7-a71f-8732044cb249",
          "accountId" : "724bee3e-38f8-4538-b944-f3e21c518437"
        }
      }
```

The document that is in our Amazon ElasticSearch

```
   {
        "_index" : "testingindex",
        "_type" : "doc",
        "_id" : "B-hP020Bd2lcvg9lTyBH",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "customerId" : [
            "e177c1f8-1fbd-4b2e-82b8-760536e42742"
          ],
          "customProperty" : {
            "messageFrom" : [
              "BOT"
            ]
          },
          "@version" : "1",
          "userId" : [
            "e177c1f8-1fbd-4b2e-82b8-760536e42742"
          ],
          "@timestamp" : "2019-10-16T06:44:13.154Z",
          "uniqueIdentifier" : "2b027fc0-a517-49a7-a71f-8732044cb249",
          "accountId" : "724bee3e-38f8-4538-b944-f3e21c518437"
        }
      }
```

@Version and @Timestamp are the new two fields are getting added in documents

Can anyone explain why it is getting added is there any other way to prevent this?
As you compare both documents the `_type` and `_id` also getting changed we need both `_type` and  `_id` same as our documents in self hosted Elasticsearch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fields `@version` and `@timestamp` are generated by logstash, if you don't want them you will need to use a mutate filter to remove.

```
mutate {
    remove_fields => ["@version","@timestamp"]
}
```

To keep the `_type` and `_id` of your original documents, you will need to change your input and add the option `docinfo => true` to get those fields into the `@metadata` field and use them in your output, the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-elasticsearch.html#plugins-inputs-elasticsearch-docinfo) has an example for this.

```
input {
    elasticsearch {
        ...
        docinfo => true
    }

output {
    elasticsearch {
        ...
        document_type => "%{[@metadata][_type]}"
        document_id => "%{[@metadata][_id]}"
    }
}
```

Note that if your Amazon Elasticsearch is version 6.X or higher, you can only have one document type per index, and version 7.X is [typeless](https://www.elastic.co/blog/moving-from-types-to-typeless-apis-in-elasticsearch-7-0), also, logstash version 7.X does not have the `document_type` option anymore.